# Set combobox Item in code Behind UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I have seen how to select the item from the index by code behind, but how can i select it from code behind knowing the string of the item?

combobox code xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxOne" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="40" Width="200">
      <ComboBoxItem Content="blue"/>
      <ComboBoxItem Content="red"/>
      <ComboBoxItem Content="green"/>
</ComboBox>
```

combobox code behind:

```
ComboBoxOne.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

But how to select the item knowing for example green? Is possible?

I tried with ComboBoxOne.PlaceholderText

```
ComboBoxOne.PlaceholderText="green"
```

But then I can not use the selecteditem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to get the `Items` of the `ComboBox` as a `List` to find the Index of the item that you want to select by string. Since this will be a `List<String>` you can do something like below.

```
List<String> lstItems = ComboBoxOne.Items
                            .Cast<ComboBoxItem>()
                            .Select(item => item.Content.ToString())
                            .ToList();
```

and then you can get the index using `Linq` and assign it to Selected Index. Like below.

```
ComboBoxOne.SelectedIndex = lstItems.FindIndex(a => a.Equals("green"));
```

Good Luck.