# Set the ComboBox's SelectedItem to the object from ListBox UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I have got a list view which populates my chart of accounts:

```
public class ChartOfAccounts
{
    public int AccountCode { get; set; }
    public string AccountTitle { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string SubCategory { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

Through this list view, I want to populate other controls like:

```
private void MainRadDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.DataGridSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RadDataGrid rdg = (RadDataGrid)sender;

    var SelectedCOA = (ChartOfAccounts)rdg.SelectedItem;

    if (rdg !=null && rdg.SelectedItems.Count > 0) {
        AccountCodeTextBox.Text = SelectedCOA.AccountCode.ToString();
        AccountTitleTextBox.Text = SelectedCOA.AccountTitle;
        DescriptionTextBox.Text = SelectedCOA.Description;
        CategoryComboBox.SelectedItem = SelectedCOA.Category;

        SubCategoryComboBox.SelectedItem = SelectedCOA.SubCategory;
    }
}
```

The problem is, that I could not set the `Category` and `SubCategory` Comboboxes to the related `Category` and `SubCategory`. ComboBox only shows `Category` and `Sub Category` word, not the actual selected item.

Can anyone explains why this is not working?

Comment: What do you set to CategoryComboBox.ItemsSource?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the selected item in a comboBox to match my string using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450059/how-do-i-set-the-selected-item-in-a-combobox-to-match-my-string-using-c)

Comment: You cannot set the SelectedItem Directly without setting the ItemsSource. Also See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46978988/set-combobox-item-in-code-behind-uwp/46980423#46980423) answer on how to properly select the item.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your answer is this:

```
CategoryComboBox.SelectedItem = Combox1.FindStringExact(SelectedCOA.Category.?) // ? = displayed cat name
```

or

```
CategoryComboBox.SelectedIndex = CategoryComboBox.Items.IndexOf(SelectedCOA.Category.?);
```